# Analog of IT term “костыль” in English

Tags: сленг, software, it

I am not sure if this is a proper place to post this question, but I was unable to find any better.

In software development, we tend to use the Russian word “костыль” (crutch) to denote a solution that's used to prop the existing code up, not to fix the real cause of the problem. It’s wry and usually used in a negative sense, like “I’ll put a crutch here for now, but when we have time, it should be fixed properly.” The code behaves like a human being on crutches: they're somehow able to walk, but those watching fear that they can fall down any minute.

My question is: does “crutch” sound legit in this context in English, and if not, is there any close analog of “костыль” in English?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not about the Russian language.

Comment: @YellowSky I could easily state the question as ‘is “crutch” to be translated into Russian as “костыль” in IT slang’ to make it fit rules better, and receive a feedback on the real question. Instead of doing that I honestly stated the question the way it goes. I believe it’s related to Russian language and is in general “about the Russian language.” Sometimes following rules blindly is the worst thing we can do.

Comment: Hack or workaround.

Comment: it's kludgy - http://www.thefreedictionary.com/kludgy - but this is off-topic here.

Comment: @shabunc oh, thanks. I understood the question is a bit off-topic from the scratch, but I could not figure out where I can ask this question, save for this hub. Thanks.

Comment: @mudasobwa, the question is about English language, so you can ask it at http://english.stackexchange.com/. Your explanation of the word is quite good, so it's not necessary to know Russian to answer your question.

Comment: The word is "kludge"

Comment: @axk thanks, I know it now, but still I appreciate your digging here.

Comment: In English, we tend to call something like what you're describing, a band-aid. See meaning 2: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/band-aid

Comment: I'm sorry this question was closed. I think it's an interesting linguistic question in both languages. Sometimes I wish there were more flexibility on here.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin This article deals with band-aids used in IT and project management: https://lucidinsights.com.au/industry-trends-and-news/agile-series-no-9-solutions-are-great-band-aids-are-not/

Comment: @CocoPop thanks for the link, I appreciate it!

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin If this question were still open, I would've posted an official response. My sister's a project manager here in Florida, and she confirmed that band-aid is what they call this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use "dirty hack" in such cases. I don't think "hack" or "workaround" have such negative connotations.

Comment: In terms of IT we also can use term "ad hoc" (a bit Latin)

Comment: We also use the "duct tape". Or "workaround" when talking to management.